# Subspace topology of compact open topology for the bounded continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I would like to apply the Ascoli theorem for non compact spaces and I found in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05693.pdf) paper [this](https://download.tuxfamily.org/openmathdep/analysis_real/General_Topology-Kelley.pdf) book and in the book I found the theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be regular, locally compact topological space and $Y$
> a metric space. Let $C(X,Y)$ be equipped with the compact open
> topology, i.e. the topology of compact convergence, i.e. sequences in
> C(X) converge if and only if they converge uniformly on every compact set, and $F\subseteq C(X,Y)$ a family of continuous functions, then $F$ is
> compact if and only if $F$ is closed, the set $\{f(x)∣f\in F\}$ has
> compact closure in $Y$ for all $x\in X$ and $F$ is equicontinuous.

Now if $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and we consider the space $C_b(X)\subseteq C(X)$ equipped with the sup-norm, then I would like to use the above theorem to say something about compact sets in this space. But I need to show that the subspace topology is the same as the topology given by the norm.

One direction is trivial: If a sequence converges uniformly in $C_b(X)$, then it also converges uniformly on every compact set.

I have the feeling that the other direction does not hold, because I couldn't prove it. If $u_n\rightarrow u$ uniformly on every compact set, then how can I say something about convergence on the whole space? We don't know if $X$ can be covered by countalby many compact sets, as we didn't assume $X$ to be $\sigma$-compact. But even if we assume $X$ to be $\sigma$-compact, I don't see a way how to control all the terms simultaneously.

**Questions.**

1. Is it possible to prove that the topologies are equivalent in this setting? Or do you have a counter example?
2. If we require more regularity for $X$ can we prove the result then?
3. My goal would be to show that a closed set $F\subseteq C_b(X)$ is compact if and only if it is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded. Is there a way to do it perhaps without this consideration?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question. You give $C_b(X)$ the uniform topology (where $\mathbb{R}$ carries its euclidean metric) and $C(X)$ you give the compact-open topology? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely. But as a subspace of $C(X)$, $C_b(X)$ also inherits the subspace topology. So are the two the same?

Comment: I see. If $X$ is compact, then the topologies are the same, but in the non-compact case I didn't get any further than you did. It's worth mentioning that since the uniform topology is finer than the compact-open topology, any set which is compact in the uniform topology must also be compact in the compact-open topology.

Comment: Take $X=\mathbb{R}$. Let $f_n$ be a bump function which is $1$ at $n$ and is zero outside of $[n-1,n+1]$. Then $f_n\rightarrow 0$ uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but $f_n\not\rightarrow 0$ uniformly.

Comment: I think @Tyrone's example may be reproduced in any other non-compact space $X$ so, besides assuming that $X$ is compact, not much can be saved.  However, $C_b(X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(\beta(X))$, where $\beta(X)$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$, so a further analysis considering equi-continuity on $\beta(X)$ may work.

Comment: Proxova, I came across [this recent paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166864118306254) yesterday which might be of some interest to you.